# Is image button supported in Tabris iOS client?

Tags: mobile

I am new to Tabris and RAP. I am trying out Tabris using demo project downloaded from git repository

Question: Does Tabris or Tabris iOS client support image buttons?

I understand that it is possible to use label and set image to it. Also change label image on mouse down and up to mimic image button. But I found image transition was not smooth (give flicker effect) as a result it doesn't give native effect. May be I am doing something wrong. I am sure there should be solution which I am not aware of. Can you please provide suggestion as how to resolve this. Curious to know if there is any proper way to do image button other than using label.

Answer (score 1):

Themability of a `Button` will come at a later point for Tabris. The focus is right now lies on providing the SWT API and now we are working on more abstract navigation support, gestures and sensors (Camera, ...) - Geolocation is already available.

The `Button` implementation on iOS does not rely on a stretched image like other native iOS App use to do it - Tabris really draws/renders the Buttons. This allows you to fully control the colors on them.

So you are right. Currently only a Label with `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` Listeners will provide your requested functionality. But you will always have a small lag with the Label/Listener approach because of the server turnaround. The images will be cached on the client once they were transferred.

I also want to mention that it is already possible to call `setImage( image )` on a `Button`.